# c# How can I use EPPlus to create an Excel range instead of a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

Using C#, I am trying to take a csv file and create an Excel file from it using an EPPlus library. I am able to do so. After creating the Excel file, I pass it to a user who opens it in Excel. When he opens it, the file opens as a table, as opposed to a range. In Excel, one can go to Table Tools/Design, and click on Convert to Range. The user has requested that I create the Excel file in such a way that he will not have to go through the conversion step each time. I am unable to find to find a way to do it. I tried using different parameters for `LoadFromText` without success. Here is my code:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
.
.
.
FileInfo txtFile = new FileInfo(textFileName);
FileInfo xlsxFile;

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var XLformat = new ExcelTextFormat
    {
        Delimiter = OutputDelimiter[0],                 
        TextQualifier = textQualifier,                  
        SkipLinesBeginning = 0,                         
        Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),  
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,                       
        SkipLinesEnd = 1                                
    };

    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);

    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(txtFile, XLformat, TableStyles.None, true);

    sheet.Tables[0].ShowFilter = false;

    package.SaveAs(xlsxFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
sheet.Tables[0].ShowFilter = false;
```

with

```
sheet.Tables.Delete(0);
```

That way you remove the table but keep the data as range.

Edit:

There is a easier way, which is not create a table at all, just use the right overload:

```
sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(txtFile, XLformat);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used `sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(txtFile, XLformat);` and it worked